# How can I make the currently selected todo get updated with the modified value?

Tags: reactjs, edit, react-hooks

I am making a todo app to sharpen my react skills with hooks and I want to make a function updateTask to update the currently selected task with whatever I type in the input after the getCurrentTask function is triggered, which populates the input value with the currently selected task's text value.

This is the updateTask function:

```
function updateTask(statePlaceholder, id) {
  const updatedTaskIndex = statePlaceholder.tasks.findIndex(
    task => task.id === id
  );
  const updatedTask = statePlaceholder.tasks.map(task => {
    return { ...task, text: statePlaceholder.currentTask.text };
  });
  const updatedTasks = [
    ...statePlaceholder.tasks.slice(0, updatedTaskIndex),
    updatedTask,
    ...statePlaceholder.tasks.slice(updatedTaskIndex + 1)
  ];

  return {
    ...statePlaceholder,
    tasks: updatedTasks,
    currentTask: null
  };
}
```

and I use this function in the handleSubmit function in the form

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    state.currentTask
      ? setState(updateTask(state, state.currentTask.id))
      : setState(createTask(state, value));

    setValue("");
  }
```

I want to be able to update the currently selected task.

Comment: Just a hint: not many people gonna find time to go through your whole code on sandbox. If you wan to get some useful answers, you'd post the relevant _code parts_ here.

Comment: Considering the error says `two children with the same key`, have you tried playing around with the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are is an error in your `updateTask` function, but before coming to that there is a suggestion.

Looks like you are using composite state, like

```
[state, setState] = useState({tasks:[], current:0})
```

Instead more idiomatic way is to use separate state variables:

```
[tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
[current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
```

This will also make your state management much more easier.

Now coming back to error in `updateState`, after retrieving `updatedTaskIndex`, you need to 1) retrieve the `originalTask`, 2) mutate it and 3) put it back in right position in new array. You are not doing #1 and hence #2 you are attempting will produce wrong result. Do something like

```
origTask = tasks[taskIndex];
updatedTask = {...origTask, text: text}
```

Comment: This solution worked.
This the line I had to add, which as you said it would retrieve the original, aka the selected task.

 const selectedTask = statePlaceholder.tasks.find(task => task.id === id);

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is basically returning a collection of updates tasks.

And then the problem is that you're having duplicate keys in your statePlaceholder.tasks list

Why you need to replace the text in *all* your statePlaceholder.tasks,

It seems that you are returning **an array** here (many tasks a**nd not just one task**) so this causes later on the duplicate keys error

```
 const updatedTask = statePlaceholder.tasks.map(task => {
    return { ...task, text: statePlaceholder.currentTask.text };
  });
```

its better that change to:

```
      const updatedTask = statePlaceholder.tasks.filter(task => task.id === id)
      updatedTask.text= statePlaceholder.currentTask.text;

      const updatedTasks = [
        ...statePlaceholder.tasks.slice(0, updatedTaskIndex),
        updatedTask,
        ...statePlaceholder.tasks.slice(updatedTaskIndex + 1)
      ];
```

so I looked at your code posted at the sandbox and the problem is that 
function updateTask(statePlaceholder, id)

parameter id is arriving as undefined, and then updatedTaskIndex -> -1

You are only setting **the name** of the task and not the object(with the id) here:

```
  <input
        type="text"
        className="App_input"
        placeholder="Type Task"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
```

Comment: Actually, when I try to edit a task and I submit its duplicating all the other tasks witout changing the edited one